# How to use Google fonts in a React application using Next.js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, fonts, next.js

I am building a basic React app using Next.js and want to know how I would use Google fonts in the app.

Is it possible to import the fonts in each component or do I need to make a main stylesheet?

Comment: This might be stupid but... I would just include a normal link in the head like you would in plain html. Just the link you get from google. And make sure you have your styles using that font.

Comment: Put this in your _document.js head: `<script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: '</script><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap" media="print" onload="this.media=\'all\'" /><script>' }} />`
[source](https://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/load-css-simpler/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easily add font to your app (globally) by creating custom `document` for `next.js` app (needs to be in `pages` folder and named `_document.js`)

```
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document';

class CustomDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps (ctx) {
    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)
    return { ...initialProps }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head>
          <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}

export default CustomDocument;
```

You can read more about it [here](https://nextjs.org/docs#custom-document).

Comment: Although this works - Resources are blocking the first paint of your page in Google page insights.